# Inductive proof for Fermat's little theorem.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic, solution-verification

I'm reading Vinberg's A course in Algebra and came across this question.

It is proved for a group $\mathbb Zp$ (p prime), that $(a+b)^p = a^p+b^p$.

The question is, Conclude from the aforesaid that every $a\in \mathbb Z_p$ satisfies the identity $a = a^p$.

Here is my proof by induction. I need to check whether my approach is correct. Specially when proving for the negative integers.

First, I prove the case for $n=1$.

From the above statement I have, $(a+b)^p = a^p+b^p$ for some $a\neq0$. Let $b=0$. Now, $(1a)^p = 1a^p$, This implies $1^p=1$ which is obvious.

Now, we assume $k^p=k$ for some $k\in \mathbb N$. Now set $b=ka$ which results in $(a+ka)^p=a^p+(ka)^p$. Since $k^p = k$ the above simplifies to $(k+1)^p\times a^p=a^p+ka^p.$ This implies, $(k+1)^p=1+k.$

By the principle of mathematical induction, we can show that  $n = n^p$ for any natural number $n$.

But we need the proof for any integer (for negative integers too). So set $n=-a$ and repeat the above induction proof.

The case $a=0$ is trivial. Therefore, we can conclude that $a = a^p$ for any integer $a$.

Comment: No need to prove it for negative integers, as $\Bbb Z_p=\{0,1,2,3,\dots,p-1\}$.

Comment: @Berci ah yes! also, how can I conclude that the maximum integer in the proof is $a=p-1$. The proof verifies for any $a \in \mathbb N$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof seems unnecessarily complicated.

We have the base case

Assuming it's true for $k$.  Then $k^p\cong k\pmod p$.

Then $(k+1)^p\cong k^p+1^p\cong k+1\square$.

Comment: How to restrict $k$ in the range $(0,1,2,...,p-1)$ ?

Comment: I get it now. "If 0 then x" results in 1 for any x = 0 or 1. Therefore, since $k$ is not defined for integers greater than $p-1$ it doesn't matter whether the statement is true or false for integers greater than $p-1$. It always returns true.